# SharePoint warmup script for FBA authentication

Tags: sharepoint, forms-authentication

I was looking for some warmup script but all the scripts I found on net are based on windows authentication and which doesn't work with FBA. I found this article though 
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/yasinalladin/archive/2009/06/13/moss-warmup-script-for-fba-based-internet-facing-site.aspx which uses authentication web services to login but it also resulted in error as mentioned in the comments at the bottom of the article.

Anyone knows about it?

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a reference to the `http://[site-collection-URL]/_vti_bin/Authentication.asmx` Web service in your project and call it `FBAPORTAL` (if you want to use another name, you need to modify the code appropriately).

Comment: but I don't want this script to be specific to one site collection , If I wanna use the same script in different farms....If there is any way to not mention the site collection name in the code?

Comment: @PJ12 Adding the reference using a specific URL **doesn't mean** that the code will work for only one site collection. This URL is only used by Visual Studio to retrieve information about the Web service and build the proxy class - later it can be dynamically changed in the code (i.e. `webServiceClient.Url = webServiceUrl`).